# Correctly passing string based parameters with PetaPoco

Tags: c#, petapoco

Whilst working with PetaPoco in our development environment, we wrote a Fetch command a little like this:

```
DB.Fetch<object>("SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Tablename WHERE Col1 = @0, parameter)
```

The resultant command looks a lot like this:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Tablename WHERE Col1 = parameter
```

In most database versions, this is fine, however when the target database was moved to an environment running SQL Server 2014, it becomes apparent that this isn't good enough any more - SQL Server 2014 enforces the requirement to wrap varchar/string based parameters in single quotes, whereas previous versions were able to make a type determination at the point the query is executed and this was never an issue.

I can't reproduce the issue, as I don't have a SQL Server 2014 environment to hand, but it's apparent that SQL is trying to parse what it thinks is an integer to a string and comes out with what looks like a Hex value. Not a particularly helpful indication of what's happening, I grant you

The logical conclusion would be to adapt our Fetch to look something like this:

```
DB.Fetch<object>("SELECT Col1, Col2 FRMO Tablename WHERE Col1 = '@0', parameter)
```

Annoyingly, our last command looks like this:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Tablename WHERE Col1 = '@0'
```

I've tried a number of different ways of writing my fetch command, including using a SqlParameter object as the first argument in the parameter array, defining the type as varchar, but I cannot get the query to work as I'd expect. The closest I have come is to use either string.Format, or an interpolated string, but this poses an obvious security risk and I'd rather avoid it.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251758/petapoco-parameter-being-treated-as-literal) which seems to suggest that the 'correct' thing to do is to remove the single quotes, however as I say, this is a breaking behaviour in MSSQL 2014+...

Is this not a supported feature of PetaPoco, or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I would actually be very surprised if it didn't work by default without the quotes so without you being able to reproduce the issue, it is very hard to find a reason. However, you could help in making it easier to reproduce for us if you would have an example of a connection string and how you create the database, and a simple table that represents a structure that would need this querying, without an MVCE it is very hard to decide if the problem is on your side or on the PETAPOCO side

Comment: As an extra info, what do you send as `parameter`?

Comment: PetaPoco maintainer here. You don't need quotes when using parameters, as the db engine will use the parameters directly. What happens when you do something like `DB.Fetch<string>("SELECT @0", "test")`?